# why the text color of the frame's name in rviz is white?

Tags: ros, rviz, frame, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why the text color of the frame's name in rviz is white?

Is it white because that background of the rviz is black?  If yes, what if we change it to white? Can we change the text color of the frame's name in rviz to black? If yes, how?

I change background of the rviz from black to white easly, but the text color of the frame's name is impossible to change it from rviz screen. Which is file of configuration whose is responsible for it?

[image: image description]

**update**

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357236/why-the-text-color-of-the-frame%27s-name-in-rviz-is-white?/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2020-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is basically hard-coded in the tf display type plugin:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/melodic-devel/src/rviz/default_plugin/tf_display.cpp#L564

("basically", because in case of a timeout it will turn grey...)

So there is no way for you to change that except for changing the source code.

As to why it is white in the first place, my guess is as good as any, but I'd also say due to the default background being black...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-07-15**:
I did not find tf_display.cpp in my computer, but I found tf_display.h which does not include color's lines.

I will add figure to my question as update.
Will I need to build it as own visualization from source? If yes, does it need to modify something in launch file?

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-07-15**:
I downloaded it for kinetic from [kinetic-devel](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/kinetic-devel/src/rviz/default_plugin/tf_display.cpp) and put it on my `/catkin_ws/src/`

I changed this line from

```
frame->name_text_->setColor(Ogre::ColourValue::White);
```

to

```
frame->name_text_->setColor(Ogre::ColourValue::Black);
```

and used `catkin_make`,

then used `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

It works fine,

thank you so much for your help.

Note: all this modification is in the workstation part, not is in the robot part.